# Interrupt and restart write operation

Tags: python, file-io, pickle, slurm

I am currently running a piece of Python code on a cluster. Part of the rules enforced upon me by slurm are that there is a timelimit on the wallclock run time of my code. This isn't really a problem most times as I can simply checkpoint my code using pickle and then restart it.

At the end of the code I, however, need to write out all my data (I can't write until all calculations have been finished) which can take some time as very large pieces of data can be gathered.

My problem is now that in some cases the code gets terminated by slurm because it exceeded its run time allowance.

Is there some way of interrupting a write operation, stopping the code and then restarting where I left off?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you put your data in a list or tuple.
perhaps a generator function?

```
#Create generator function
def Generator():
    data=['line1','line2','line3','line4']:
    for i in data:
        yield i    
output=Generator() #reference it
.......
......

if [time conditions is true]:   
     file-open("myfile","a")
     file.write(str(next(output))
else:
     [Do something]
```

You can also use try capturing the exception and restart your main function

```
try:
    MainFunction() #main function with generator next calls
except [you error Error]:
    MainFunction() #restart main function
```

Comment: When I reach the timeout condition my entire code has to be terminated (either forcibly or I do it myself after some cleanup). How would I know where I left off when I restart?

Comment: "forcibly"....i see..why not capture the exception and restart your Main function?

Comment: The code is submitted with a batch file and when it hits timeout that instance of the python interpreter is terminated. The only way to restart the last run is by writing information to the hard drive and reading it in again during a new job. Capturing exceptions in a higher level function is not possible.